# Joomla template for technical documentation website

Tags: templates

I'm looking for a template for Joomla 3 suitable for a website for technical documentation.

I have to reconfigure this site: http://help.logicaldoc.com

What I need is a professional template, regardless of the cost, provided specifically for the display of technical documentation.

I saw some document authoring software like Adobe RoboHelp or HelpSmith and the Web sites produced using these software are interesting, I'm looking for a template of that type

Comment: I don't know what kind of site the above software can create, but I know that with a few lines of css you could customize the default or any other joomla template and make it look the way you want.

Comment: Are you simply looking for template recommendations?

Comment: Hi @johnny_s, I could use, I know many template vendors, but I have not seen any template specific for sites of technical documentation. If you knew it would save me a lot of time

Comment: +1 for RocketTheme. Very old post, but I found myself in the similar circumstances and stumbled upon this thread. A nicety IMHO of RocketTheme is their [compatibility matrix](https://rockettheme.com/joomla-templates-compatibility-matrix). Coming from product management background, I REALLY appreciate their effort in this regard.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Rather than looking for a template `provided specifically for the display of technical documentation`, (which I doubt you'll find), you should look for a template that has a look you like. Try seeing beyond the demo content that template providers usually add in order to show what the template is capable of.

Remember that the frontpage of these demo sites is usually loaded with modules and functions that you probably don't want (nor should) add to your site. Look at other pages to see how articles are rendered, or how the contact form is displayed.

Your best option is probably to look for business templates, they usually has a clean and professional look. Many template providers uses a tag system to make it easier to find a suitable template, here are a couple of links to the `Business` tag (if available) of some popular template providers:

- Gavick Pro: https://www.gavick.com/joomla-templates/tag,business.html
- JoomlaBamboo: http://www.joomlabamboo.com/joomla-templates/joomla-business-templates
- Shape5: http://www.shape5.com/product_details/club_templates/
- RocketTheme: http://www.rockettheme.com/joomla/templates
- JoomlArt: http://www.joomlart.com/joomla/templates/tag/business
- YooTheme: http://yootheme.com/demo/joomla